# How can I fix this code? i use integer variable for array index

Tags: java, arrays, methods

** does not work as expected and I don't know what's wrong.

i use integer variable for array index
and in a method i Determine the value for variable **

---

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

```
static Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);
static int count = 0;
static int nameNum;
static String[] name = new String [nameNum];

public static void main (String [] args){

    readNameNum();
    readName();
    showNameList();


}

public static int readNameNum (){

    System.out.println("Enter number of names");
    System.out.print("> ");
    nameNum = key.nextInt();
    return nameNum;

}

public static void readName (){

    System.out.println("Enter "+nameNum+" names");

    for (int i = 0; i < nameNum; i++){

        count++;

        System.out.print("N"+count+": ");
        name [i] = key.next();

    }


}

public static void showNameList (){

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){

        System.out.println(name [i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize this `nameNum` variable before use it:

```
  static int nameNum= 20;// ex 20
```

Or if you want i suggest to use something like this:

```
 static String[] name = null;
 public static void main (String [] args){

    name = new String [readNameNum()];
    readName();
    showNameList();
 }
```

Comment: when i  use literal  not have problem but i need get data frome inpunt

Comment: `public static void readName (){`name = new String [nameNum];

Answer (score 0):

You create the array of String before you know how many elements it should have.

```
static int nameNum; // == 0
static String[] name = new String [nameNum]; // doesn't magically change size.

nameNum = key.nextInt(); // doesn't change the `name`
```

I suggest you only create the array once you know what size it should be i.e. after you have read it.

Before you fix this bug, you should step through your program in your debugger to confirm this is the problem.